# How to repeat a command with an added parameter

Tags: bash, command-history

I know how to repeat a command and add more text after it with `!!` like so:

```
ls -l
!! tmp
```

The second line expands to `ls -l tmp`.

But what if I wanted to add parameters to the command in between the words? For example if I've done the following:

```
ls tmp
```

...then I would often want to add the `-l` parameter to the command but not retype the whole thing or press up and use arrow keys to set the cursor to the correct place. `!! -l` doesn't work because it becomes `ls tmp -l` which is not valid. (In practice the command is much longer than the simple example I've used here.)

In other words I'm looking for something like `?? -l` where `??` is something that repeats the previous command but adds `-l` in between the first and second words.

---

Just to make it clear, `ls -l tmp` is just a simplified example. The real-life use case is closer to something like `/very/long/path/to/very-long-command --with=a --very=long --parameter=list`.

Comment: For the example it can be `^ ^ -l ^` which exchange `space` for `space -l space` or `^s^s -l^`(but `ls tmp -l` is workable too)

Comment: Try `!!:0 -l /tmp`. Here `0` means first word, ie. the command itself. Of course you can also do `!!:0 -l !!:1` if you don't want to repeat `/tmp`.

Comment: Both of those seem to work. You should add them as answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!!:0` is the 0'th word of the previous command, and `!!:*` is all the words except the 0'th.

```
!!:0 -l !!:*
```

is the command you're looking for.

Source https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Designators

Comment: This was really helpful for me. I will often try to checkout a new git branch, but forget the `-b` flag that opens a new branch. So I might type out `git checkout whatever`, to add in the `-b` that I need, I can do this: `!!- -b !$` because `!!-` is everything but the last word, and `!$` is the last word.

Answer (score 3):

You can:

```
$ ls -l
[..]
$ !:0* /tmp
[..]
```

This will call `ls -l /tmp`. See the `bash` manual page:

```
   Word Designators
       Word designators are used to select desired words from the event.  A : separates the 
       event specification from the  word  designator.   It  may  be  omitted  if the word
       designator begins with a ^, $, *, -, or %.  Words are numbered from the beginning of
       the line, with the first word being denoted by 0 (zero).  Words are inserted into the
       current line separated by single spaces.

       0 (zero)
              The zeroth word.  For the shell, this is the command word.
       n      The nth word.
       ^      The first argument.  That is, word 1.
       $      The last argument.
       %      The word matched by the most recent `?string?' search.
       x-y    A range of words; `-y' abbreviates `0-y'.
       *      All of the words but the zeroth.  This is a synonym for `1-$'.  It is not an 
              error to use * if there is just one  word  in
              the event; the empty string is returned in that case.
       x*     Abbreviates x-$.
       x-     Abbreviates x-$ like x*, but omits the last word.

       If a word designator is supplied without an event specification, the previous command
       is used as the event.
```

Comment: Better to refer to `man history`

Comment: This looks promising, but the example is the wrong way around. How do you go from `ls /tmp` to `ls -l /tmp`?

Answer (score 1):

Bash allows you to do quickly search and get back in your prompt a command from your history so you could then edit it by hand before executing it.

At the prompt:

1. Press **Ctrl-R** (like in **R**everse): the prompt should change in order to inform you that you are now in Reversed mode,
2. Begin to type any part of your command (in your example you might type `ls`, `tmp`, or even `mp` to match `ls tmp`): the last used command matching your key strokes will be shown as you type.
3. Once you've found your command, just type `tab` to get it in your normal prompt: it will not be executed yet, it will be here awaiting for your modifications, for instance any parameter addition, removal or change, or applying a different command to the same file, etc.

Comment: Pressing *Enter* will trigger the command, at least on my system. Use *Tab* instead ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way that doesn't involve retyping the command.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith: Thanks, mistake corrected (I don't have any Bash at hand currently and at the end it just becomes a reflex so I use the history without thinking which actual key I press :) )

Comment: @Moyli You have to reach the right command somehow. If it's the previous one, just press `Up` instead of typing `!!`. If it's an earlier command, press `Ctrl+R foo` instead of `!foo` (not exactly the same but close enough).

Comment: @Gilles The premise is that it's the immediately previous command. I've mentioned all this in the question, including that I'm looking for a way that doesn't involve retyping or moving around with cursor keys. The other answer shows (almost) how to do it without retyping the command.

Comment: @Moyli This answer focuses on searching older commands. If you want to edit the last command, just press `Up`. No retyping is involved.

Comment: @Gilles But moving inside the command with arrow keys is involved, which is specifically what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

To launch the previous command with an option added immediately after the command name, press the following keys:
<kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> (type the option) <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If cursor keys don't work on your system, you can use Emacs motion keys instead:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> (type the option) <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If the command name has multiple words (e.g. because it's a path with slashes), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> only moves past the first slash. Search the first space instead.

<kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> (type the option) <kbd>Enter</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> (type the option) <kbd>Enter</kbd>

With this search, you can start with <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> instead of <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Home</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. The number of key presses is the same, but it's slightly easier to type but less intuitive.

If you prefer, you can use the [history substitution facility](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Event-Designators-1), which involves fewer key presses if the command contains slashes.
`^ ^ --option ﻿`
Note the trailing space after the option: you're replacing the first space in the command by a space, the new option, and another space.